# What are the frameworks of Drupal and Joomla?

Tags: drupal, joomla, php

Do Drupal and Joomla use any common PHP frameworks or do they implement their own?

Comment: Check the Joomla tag wiki on this website. "powered by an MVC-oriented framework." ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal by it self is a framework! Drupal is known to be a great open source web content management system, but that view is to limiting. Drupal has a great set of APIs and you can switch off almost every functionality (module) in Drupal till you end up with a core system. Using contributed modules and the APIs you can then create a totally new web application on top of this.

All this is true for Drupal 5 - 7. With the release of Drupal 8 things will change quite a bit. The Drupal community has decided to use several components of the Symfony2 framework to power the core of Drupal 8. This means that some to many Drupal core sub systems will be powered by Symfony2 components and Drupal code. As the development of D8 is an ongoing process, it's hard to say how much "Symfony2 awesomeness" will be implemented. One thing is for sure, both communities are looking forward to see the results. :)

Symfony: http://symfony.com/

Drupal + Symfony: http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-meets-drupal-8

Answer (score 2):

Drupal and Joomla are CMS i.e. Content Management Systems

You can use them as frameworks. They are in-built frameworks.

See:

1. [Difference between CMS(joomla,drupal) and Frameworks(Zend, Symfony, CI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797459/difference-between-cmsjoomla-drupal-and-frameworkszend-symfony-ci)
2. http://steveburge.com/blog/general-cms-issues/joomla-and-drupal-version-2/